# Ppointer and data structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

My goal is to create a push function for my data structure.

What I'm trying to do:

1. ask a client to enter a three character obj word eg. box
2. the obj name will then be passed to the push function(for now the head and tail pointer's are null)
3. the computer will then allocate memory for this, and then the function will return a memory address
4. I will then use that address to store the obj name to my object Array.

I'm trying to do this data structure step by step, and as for now I cannot seem to save the obj name to the objArray. Can I not return a pointer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *push(char element, char *head, char *tail){
    char *dq;
    dq = (char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
    head=dq;
    return head;
}

int main(){
    char input[7];
    char command[7];
    char objArr;
    char objname[4];
    char *head;
    char *tail;

while(printf("Choose from the ff operations by typing:\npush\npop\ninject\neject\nexit\nInput Command: ")&&fgets(input, 6, stdin)){
    sscanf(input, "%s", command);

    if(strcmp(command, "exit")==0){
        break;
    }
    if(strcmp(command, "push")==0){
        printf("Input an object name to push: ");
        fgets(objname, 4, stdin);

        head = push(objname, *head, *tail);
        objArr[head] = objname;
        printf("%s", objArr[head]);
        break;
    }

    if(strcmp(command, "pop")==0){
        break;
    }

    if(strcmp(command, "inject")==0){
        break;
    }

    if(strcmp(command, "eject")==0){
        break;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Hard to address this one, there's a huge amount wrong here. Practically every use of arrays and pointers in this program is incorrect, e.g. `objArr` is not an array but you treat it as one and try to index it with a pointer, you never copy the string in your `push()` function, you allocate memory for `dq` but never initialize it, `objname` is an array yet you pass it to a function that expects a `char`. It's a brave attempt, but it's hard to suggest anything other than reviewing the basics and trying again.

Comment: Does this compile without warning, with all warnings on (gcc options `-Wall -Wextra -pedatnic`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
 head = push(objname, *head, *tail);
```

You're dereferencing `head` and `tail` and haven't allocated any memory for it.  That's Undefined Behaviour.

Either allocate the pointer or pass it in like so:

```
 head = push(objname, head, tail);
```

There's other errors in your program too.  Like your first parameter to `push` is a `char`, yet you pass it a `char[]`